# How to pass arguments to a Dart command line program run in Sublime?

Tags: dart, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with the [Dart Sublime Bundle](https://github.com/guillermooo/dart-sublime-bundle).

I'm writing a simple command line program that will take arguments (parsed with the [args package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/args)).

While developing the program I can run it in Sublime via the command palette or (shift) F7. How can I specify arguments to pass to the program, for testing purposes?

Comment: Sorry, mixed it with WebStorm. I don't use Sublime with Dart.